# Load ImageList picture in TImage with a ComboBox

Tags: delphi

In my Delphi form I have an ImageList with 4 pictures. There are also a ComboBox called `ComboBox1` and a TImage component that is called `Image9`.

I've created an `onChange` for my ComboBox because I'd like to do a thing like this: if the ComboBox item 1 is selected, then load the image 1 in my ImageList. Same case if ComboBox item 3 is selected (for example), load the image 3 of ImageList.

The code I wrote is this:

```
case ComboBox1.Items[ComboBox1.ItemIndex] of
0:
 begin
  ImageList1.GetBitmap(0,Image9.Picture);
 end;
1:
 begin
  ImageList1.GetBitmap(1,Image9.Picture);
 end;
2:
 begin
  ImageList1.GetBitmap(2,Image9.Picture);
 end;
3:
 begin
  ImageList1.GetBitmap(3,Image9.Picture);
 end;
end;
```

With this code, the IDE (I'm using Delphi XE4) is giving me an error on `case ComboBox1.Items[ComboBox1.ItemIndex] of` because it says that an Ordinal type is required. What could I do?

Comment: case ComboBox1.ItemIndex of

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`case` statements](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Declarations_and_Statements#Case_Statements) in Delphi work on [Ordinal types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Simple_Types):

> Ordinal types include integer, character, Boolean, enumerated, and subrange types. An ordinal type defines an ordered set of values in which each value except the first has a unique predecessor and each value except the last has a unique successor. Further, each value has an ordinality, which determines the ordering of the type. In most cases, if a value has ordinality n, its predecessor has ordinality n-1 and its successor has ordinality n+1

`ComboBox.Items` are strings, and therefore don't meet the requirements of being ordinals.

Also, as noted in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2178238/dk64) below, you can't assign to `Image9.Picture` directly as you are; you have to use `Image9.Picture.Bitmap` instead. In order for the `TImage` to update properly to reflect the change, you need to call it's `Invalidate` method.)

Change your `case` to use the `ItemIndex` directly instead:

```
case ComboBox1.ItemIndex of
  0: ImageList1.GetBitmap(0,Image9.Picture.Bitmap);
  1: ImageList1.GetBitmap(1,Image9.Picture.Bitmap);
end;
Image9.Invalidate;  // Refresh image
```

Or just go directly to the `ImageList`

```
if ComboBox1.ItemIndex <> -1 then
begin
  ImageList1.GetBitmap(ComboBox1.ItemIndex, Image9.Picture.Bitmap);
  Image9.Invalidate;
end;
```

Comment: That last solution seriously decreases the amount of code. But don't forget to check if `ItemIndex` is `-1`, that is, if no item is selected. Or set the style to DropDownList and set the itemindex before showing the form, to make sure that `-1` cannot ever be selected.

Comment: @GolezTrol: Good point. I'll edit to add that check, although if the user is required to choose one from the ComboBox I would have expected the style to already be DropDownList.

Comment: sorry, I'm late. +1 by the way, very useful and complete answer :) Thank you!

Comment: @KenWhite I've noticed that if you use 'Image9.Picture' the code doesn't work. Instead, with Image9.Picture.Bitmap it's correct :)

Comment: @DK64: Thanks for that info; I didn't look closely enough at that part of the code. I've added that as a note for future readers, and updated the code to reflect that as well. Thanks for the upvote and accept as well. :-)